# Change git history and branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-history

I have 2 branches which is created at the same time from master branch. Both has been merged to master after changes. Branch history look like below:

[My git structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujNf8.png)

I want to change the structure so that Branch2 should be created from master that Branch 1 already merged. I want to change the structure to this:

[I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKHZd.png)

Is it possible to change the git history from image 1 to image 2?

Comment: Please use textual formats rather than images. Git branches and history can be displayed as a code block with ASCII text.

Answer (score 2):

Read about [branch rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), and after that you can go to your branch2 and rebasing it with master